# VBA ActiveWorkbook.Saveas runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I am new to VBA and trying to make a copy from ws to wscsv and save the latter as .csv file. The following is my sub routine.

I am encountering:

> run-time error 1004: Application undefined

at this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=savedirectory, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges  

csvworkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

**My Code**

```
Sub AddNewWorkbook1(ws As Worksheet)

  ws.Activate
  MsgBox ("adding new workbook for" & ws.Name)
  Dim wscsv As Excel.Workbook
  Dim savedirectory As String
  Dim currentworkbook As String
  Dim csvworkbook As String
  currentworkbook = ws.Name

  savedirectory = '/Users/Desktop/Magnum/' & currentworkbook

  Dim lrow As Long
  lrow = Columns("A").End(xlDown).Row

  Workbooks.Add
  DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (Filename:=savedirectory, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)

  csvworkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

  Set wscsv = ActiveWorkbook
  MsgBox ("Entering copying")

  ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lrow, 4)).Copy
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "H"), ws.Cells(lrow, "H")).Copy
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "E"), ws.Cells(lrow, "E")).Copy
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "I"), ws.Cells(lrow, "I")).Copy
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("G1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  lrow = wscsv.Sheets(1).Columns("A").End(xlDown).Row
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range(wscsv.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1),    wscsv.Sheets(1).Cells(lrow, 1)).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Date"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "open"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value = "high"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("D1").Value = "low"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("E1").Value = "close"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "volume"
  wscsv.Sheets(1).Range("G1").Value = "cap"
  wscsv.Save
  wscsv.Close

  MsgBox ("Copying complete")

  End Sub
```

Comment: is `currentworkbook` a `CSV`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173898/how-to-do-a-save-as-in-vba-code-saving-my-current-excel-workbook-with-datesta

Comment: No its not. its a .xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving your error line, just use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=savedirectory, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=2
```

(`ConflictResolution = 2` , equals `xlLocalSessionChanges` , read here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194803.aspx

However, you could improve your code by not using `ws.Activate` , `ActiveWorkbook` and `csvworkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name`. You could directly assign your `wscsv` (defined as workbook) to the new created workbook. See my code below how to reference all objects.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewWorkbook1(ws As Worksheet)

MsgBox ("adding new workbook for " & ws.Name)

Dim wscsv As Workbook
Dim savedirectory As String
Dim currentworkbook As String
Dim csvworkbook As String

currentworkbook = ws.Name
savedirectory = "Your Path" & "\" & ws.Name

Dim lrow As Long
lrow = ws.Columns("A").End(xlDown).Row

Set wscsv = Workbooks.Add
DisplayAlerts = False

wscsv.SaveAs Filename:=savedirectory, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=2
csvworkbook = wscsv.Name

MsgBox ("Entering copying")

' do the rest of your copy >> paste 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesnt work and give the same error. I am running this on a MacBook Air. Is it possible to be the cause?

Comment: It. Might be, but I have a PC, so I can't help u debug

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=savedirectory, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
```

Could you try this way? It worked for me.

Comment: No, still doesnt work, would it because I am using a Mac to run this?