# 1004 Error- issues with SaveAs

Tags: vba, save

```
savePath = "\\local drive path"

myFileName = savePath & "Workbook Name " & saveDate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'MsgBox (myFileName)

wbTarget.Activate

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

When using the above code, I get an error 1004 "Method SaveAs of object_Workbook failed and can't figure out why.  I'm relatively new to excel but belive I have everything set up right.

Update: Sorry should have shown the more complete code.

```
Sub SaveAs()


'Save As "Workbook Name"

Dim wbTarget            As Workbook
Dim wbThis              As Workbook
Dim strName             As String

Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Workbook Name")

wbTarget.Activate

Dim myFileName As String
Dim saveDate As String
Dim saveMonth As String
Dim monthNum As String
Dim savePath As String

Sheets("Raw").Select

saveDate = Range("A2").Value
saveMonth = Range("A2").Value
monthNum = Range("A2").Value


savePath = "\\local drive path"

myFileName = savePath & "Riskviews Data " & saveDate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'MsgBox (myFileName)

wbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook



End Sub
```

I updated the last part to say "wbTarget.SaveAs" but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a "Save As" in vba code, saving my current Excel workbook with datestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173898/how-to-do-a-save-as-in-vba-code-saving-my-current-excel-workbook-with-datesta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with `ActiveWorkBook`. You should try to avoid relying on `.Active`, `.Activate`, and `.Select` when you can simply refer to your objects directly.

Delete `wbTarget.Activate` and try the below,

```
WbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have tried to debug. `MsgBox myFileName` (notice: no `()`) should have displayed what you are passing to the save command. From your code above, it would be `\\local drive pathWorkbook Name` - noting that there is a space at the end as well. You have not defined `saveDate`, you have not added an extension and you have not indicated the file format.

See the following answers for further information to `SaveAs`.

[How to do a "Save As" in vba code, saving my current Excel workbook with datestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173898/how-to-do-a-save-as-in-vba-code-saving-my-current-excel-workbook-with-datesta)